# Get Google Discussion search results

Tags: search, web-scraping

I would like go get the results retrieved by Google Discussion Search, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=diablo%203&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&ei=qFi6T7f3FYzotQb58uSDCA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=1&ved=0CFEQ_AUoAA&biw=1366&bih=273#q=diablo%203&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=dsc&ei=q1i6T4aKLY6D-wamn7G7Cg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=5&ved=0CHMQ_AUoBA&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=88fe818faaaa8276&biw=1366&bih=273). Notice the Discussion tab on the bottom left side.

I prefer to use Python, and the Google [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/start), but I am not sure if they support the Discussion search, so any option is welcome.

Comment: It seems that it is not possible. The searchType attribute only accepts "image" and "web". If you have found a solution, let me know. I want to get discussions from google too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear to be any way the API results can be tailored to fetch 'discussion' results but the API can filter by filetype, so why not try a q query looking for the RSS feeds produced by forums?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key= your key &cx= your_id &q=diablo 3 forum RSS&fileType=rss&alt=json
```

Many tend to have a latest/ last  post feed and monitoring these for changes should produce a good stream of data.